# Installing a chrome extension in China

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I'm designing a chrome extension for a global market. According to Google's page (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting):

> As of Chrome 33, Windows stable/beta channel users can only download
>   extensions hosted in the Chrome Web store, except for installs via
>   enterprise policy or developer mode

I understand that network admins can still configure an "enterprise policy" - but what about non-enterprise users that don't have access to the chrome web store? - and yes, I'm thinking about users in China, where the CWS is blocked.

Any clever ideas (beside asking them to use VPN :/)?
TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Users may ask their friends outside China to download the installation file of specific Chrome extensions, and send to them via email or other instant chat software (QQ or others).

Or when you distribute your extensions you can attach a download url for who can not access Chrome store directly. Extensions can be installed by local file without any access to Chrome store.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer - but I suspect you may be wrong about this: I believe you can't install an extension manually unless you're in development mode. see for example - https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/26469/google-chrome-extension-disabled-in-v35-because-1password-not-in-web-store

and in addition, this solution is not something I can rely on for my production software...

Comment: Well, as a fact, CWS-packaged extensions CAN be installed from a crx file without connection to CWS. But it won't allow it to be installed from other URLs (only the drag-to-extensions-list method) and won't autoupdate from elsewehere.